# pre commit raises pylint errors on push but not when executing

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

So i have this pre-commit file:

```
repos:
- hooks:
  - args:
    - -rn
    - -sn
    - --rcfile=.pylintrc
    entry: poetry run pylint
    id: pylint
    language: system
    stages:
      - pre-commit
      - pre-push
    name: pylint
    types:
    - python
  repo: local
- hooks:
  - id: commitizen
  - id: commitizen-branch
    stages:
    - push
  repo: https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen
  rev: v3.10.0
```

and now when I want to push my code i get this error on push:

```
pylint...................................................................Failed
- hook id: pylint
- exit code: 2

************* Module account.auth.models.user
account\auth\models\user.py:17:0: E0611: No name 'mixins' in module 'painless.models' (no-name-in-module)
```

But whenever i run this command:

```
pre-commit run -a
```

everything is passed and there are no errors!

and when i run this:

```
pylint ./**
```

I get some new errors on other files.

Why `pre-commit` stage is not working?

Why am i getting different outputs for the same command? (`pre-commit run -a`)

and how can i reproduce the errors so i can fix them before committing or pushing

UPDATE:

The error that is raising by pre-commit on push doesn't mean anything to me, the is the tree of my folders and files:

```
user.py
painless/
├── __init__.py
└── models/
    └── __init__.py/
        └── mixins/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── common.py
```

The error is raising from `user.py` for this line:

```
from painless.models.mixins import TimeStampMixin
```

and i have added the module in `painless/models/mixins/__init__.py`:

```
from .common import TimeStampMixin
```

Could this be a problem related to pylint itself?

Comment: ``pylint ./**`` does not run pylint on the same set of files than the pre-commit hook. Try ``pylint . --recursive=y`` (you need to ignore your venv in your pylint conf first) to run on all the existing python files.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Ye this one does not raises any errors, but when i want to push the code the pre-push is raising one

Comment: `pass_filenames: false` and add appropriate `args` (add `.`, `--recursive`, `y` probably). Or use `ruff`, it's pre-commit- and user-friendly:)

Comment: @STerliakov i updated the question, already done those and did not fix the problem.